# PowerShell - Convert hex to string (AD export)

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I used the command CSVDE to export my active directory and want to use this data.
Everytime when there is a special german character (ä,ö,ü) the field is not readable for me.

I think it´s converted to hex because the special german letter.

I tried it now for a long time. But no solution to convert it into a human readable format :-(

How can I convert it into a readable format with PowerShell?

Thank you in advance!

For example two entrys from my export file:

> name              : X'4b6172732048c3bc626e6572'
>
> sn                : X'48c3b6626e6572'

Comment: Did you use the unicode -u switch when you exported your AD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$Encode = new-object 'System.Text.UTF8Encoding'

$encode.getstring( ( "4b6172732048c3bc626e6572"  -split '(..)' |
 ? { $_ } |  %  {[BYTE]( [CONVERT]::toint16($_,16))  } ) )

Kars Hübner
```

or one-line

```
[System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::UTF8.GetString( ( "4b6172732048c3bc626e6572"  -split '(..)' |
 ? { $_ } |  %  {[BYTE]( [CONVERT]::toint16($_,16))  } ) )
```